# PyQT user authentication and customized layouts

Tags: authentication, layout, pyqt

So I'm developing an app in PyQT and I need to implement user authentification. Basically I have drawn 3 layouts (all same size window)...on login layout, one layout for user A and one layout for user B. The the thing I want to achieve is that when user A logins he gets his specialized layout and so does B. And I want it to if possible happen in the same window (so it looks smooth...). Thanks in advance...

Comment: Some questions.. Will you only ever have two users? Do users get to choose or change their layout option? Does each layout option contain the same buttons/controls?

Comment: No...I was just using that while trying to explain...there will be more than 2 users but every user will be part of an usergroup. Each usergroup should get a different layout. The layouts are different, different widgets and everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the optional screens will contain completely different controls, I think a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstackedwidget.html) with a page for each layout option would suit your needs provided that each optional layout will take up roughly the same size area.

Comment: How would I achieve this if I have drawn all three layouts in QTDesigner? And yes all windows are exactly the same size.

Comment: You can create a main window/widget in Designer and drop a QStackedWidget on it. Right-Clicking on the stacked widget will give you a menu option to add pages. You should be able to switch to each page, open your other designed windows and cut and past your controls on to each page.